# Astar algorithm goes in endless loop

Tags: c#, a-star

I was working on A* search algorithm and I followed this: [A* search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MapData.Interfaces;

namespace MapData.Algorithm {
    public class AStar {
        IDMap map;
        List<Location2D> openset;
        List<Location2D> closedset;
        List<Location2D> path;
        Dictionary<Location2D, Double> g_scores;
        Dictionary<Location2D, Double> h_scores;
        Dictionary<Location2D, Double> f_scores;
        Dictionary<Location2D, Location2D> came_from;
        int[] ArrayX = { 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1 };
        int[] ArrayY = { 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1 };

        /// <summary>
        /// Initing the Algorithm with MapInfo
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="map">DMap info.</param>
        public AStar(IDMap map) {
            this.map = map;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Start searching untile it's find it's goal or return false.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="start">Starting Node.</param>
        /// <param name="goal">Ending Node.</param>
        public bool Find( Location2D start, Location2D goal) {
            openset = new List<Location2D>(); // The set of tentative nodes to be evaluated, initially containing the start node.
            closedset = new List<Location2D>(); // The set of nodes already evaluated.
            path = new List<Location2D>(); // The path result.
            g_scores = new Dictionary<Location2D, Double>(); // Cost from start along best known path.
            h_scores = new Dictionary<Location2D, Double>(); // Estimated cost to get from a node to the goal.
            f_scores = new Dictionary<Location2D, Double>(); // Estimated total cost from start to goal.
            came_from = new Dictionary<Location2D, Location2D>(); // The navigated nodes.


            openset.Add(start);
            g_scores[start] = 0;
            h_scores[start] = GetHValue(start, goal);
            f_scores[start] = g_scores[start] + h_scores[start];

            while (openset.Count > 0) { // while openset is not empty

                Location2D current = CheckBestNode(); //the node in openset having the lowest f_score[] value


                if (current.Equals(goal)) {
                    ReconstructPathRecursive(current);
                    return true;
                }

                Location2D neighbor = new Location2D();

                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) { // neighbor nodes.
                    neighbor.X = (ushort)(current.X + ArrayX[i]);
                    neighbor.Y = (ushort)(current.Y + ArrayY[i]);

                    bool tentative_is_better = false;

                    if (closedset.Contains(neighbor)) continue;
                    if (!map.Cells[neighbor.X, neighbor.Y].Walkable) continue;

                    Double tentative_g_score = g_scores[current] + DistanceBetween(current, neighbor);

                    if (!openset.Contains(neighbor)) {
                        openset.Add(neighbor);
                        h_scores[neighbor] = GetHValue(neighbor, goal);
                        tentative_is_better = true;
                    } else if (tentative_g_score < g_scores[neighbor]) {
                        tentative_is_better = true;
                    } else {
                        tentative_is_better = false;
                    }

                    if (tentative_is_better) {
                        if (came_from.ContainsKey(neighbor)) {
                            came_from[neighbor] = current;
                        } else {
                            came_from[neighbor] = current;
                            g_scores[neighbor] = tentative_g_score;
                            f_scores[neighbor] = g_scores[neighbor] + h_scores[neighbor];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check the best node that has the smallest f value;
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The best Node.</returns>
        Location2D CheckBestNode() {
            var BestNode = f_scores.OrderBy(x => x.Value).First().Key;
            f_scores.Remove(BestNode);
            openset.Remove(BestNode);
            closedset.Add(BestNode);
            return BestNode;
        }

        private void ReconstructPathRecursive(Location2D current_node) {
            Location2D temp;
            if (came_from.TryGetValue(current_node, out temp)) {
                ReconstructPathRecursive(temp);
                path.Add(temp);
            } else {
                path.Add(current_node);
            }
        }

        int GetHValue(Location2D start, Location2D goal) {
            int nDx = Math.Abs(start.X - goal.X);
            int nDy = Math.Abs(start.Y - goal.Y);
            if (nDx > nDy)
                return 10 * nDx + 6 * nDy;
            return 10 * nDy + 6 * nDx;
        }

        readonly Double SQRT_2 = Math.Sqrt(2);

        protected  Double DistanceBetween(Location2D inStart, Location2D inEnd) {
            int diffX = Math.Abs(inStart.X - inEnd.X);
            int diffY = Math.Abs(inStart.Y - inEnd.Y);

            switch (diffX + diffY) {
                case 1: return 1;
                case 2: return SQRT_2;
                case 0: return 0;
                default:
                    throw new ApplicationException();
            }
        }

        public List<Location2D> Path {
            get {
                return path;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have two issues:

1. If I made a check on walkable areas the Astar goes in endless loop and never finds the path nor break.
2. If I commented the part where am checking the walkable areas it finds the path but not accurate, like if the goal location is -> (444,444), the path ends at -> (444,443) or (443,444).

I can't see what am doing wrong here since I followed the Wikipedia guide.

Comment: You shouldn't just follow some guide blindly. You should understand what you're doing. Try to learn how A* should behave and then compare it with how your program.

Comment: Just a question, have you actually implemented unwalkable tiles in your Map yet?

Comment: @svick  I do understand what am doing.

Comment: @Elliot Bonneville yes I did!

Answer (score 0):

Now, correct me if I'm wrong, but it *seems* like, from looking at your other code, you want the if statements in the for loop that iterates over the current node's neighbors to look like this:

```
if (!closedset.Contains(neighbor)) continue;
if (map.Cells[neighbor.X, neighbor.Y].Walkable) continue;
```

Not like this:

```
if (closedset.Contains(neighbor)) continue;
if (!map.Cells[neighbor.X, neighbor.Y].Walkable) continue;
```

Your original code only evaluates a neighbor if it's on the closed list and it's not walkable, which I don't believe you want. The updated code evaluates a neighboring node only if it's not on the closed set and it is walkable.

For further understanding of the A* algorithm and a detailed description of how it actually works, check out [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm).

EDIT: You said your code provided an inaccurate path, that is, a path that doesn't lead all the way to the target square. From looking at your `ReconstructPathRecursive()` function, it seems like you've made a crucial mistake. Because your list contains the parent of every node traversed, you'll wind up with everything but your target square, because it isn't the parent of anything. The target square should be the first square added to your list before you begin working backwards reconstructing the path from the parent of the current node (which is the target square).

To fix this behavior, I would suggest that when you find that the current node equals the target node, you add the target node to your path list first, and after that's done, call the `ReconstructPathRecursive()` function to get the final list.

Comment: thats not correct I need to say if neighbor in closed list then continue looping , if not then check the location is walkable or not , if not continue looping if walkable then check open list etc etc , but the code you provided will continue looping if closed list does not contain neighbor , and will continue looping if the area is walkable  , it should continue looping if the area is not walkable.

Comment: Ah, I see what you did there. Well, your Walkable check seems to be causing the problem, so I would suggest looking into it more. It looks like for some reason it's always evaluating to false, e.g. your tiles are never walkable. That's the only thing I can think of that would make your loop infinite, and that's also why I asked if you had implemented walkable tiles yet. Everything else looks pretty solid to me. :)

Comment: I will check the walkable area again , but 
`if (current.Equals(goal)) {
                    path.Add(goal);
                    ReconstructPathRecursive(current);
                    return true;
                }`
It didn't fix the path am still one steep away from goal , Thanks a lot for your help ^_^

Comment: That's strange. Do you have a way of checking to see if the goal has actually been added to the list? Perhaps it's your path-traversing function that has an error somewhere.